# How to have access control for all users, including root, for R/W regular files, in Linux kernels newer than 2.6.35?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions, kernel, kernel-module

1. I have a Linux Security Module (LSM) on RedHat ES 5, kernel 2.6.18. The LSM implements access control for all users, including root, when they Read/Write regular files.
2. I'd like to implement the same functionality in CentOS 7, kernel 3.10.0.
3. However, since kernel 2.6.35, LSMs are no longer supported.

**Any ideas how can I achieve {2}?**

---

```
Note: If StackExchange has a better forum to ask this question, please suggest it in the comments.
```

Comment: #3 is not true; recent kernels have _more LSMs than ever before_.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using SELinux (configuring/writing a custom policy)?

Comment: Thanks, @grawity: do you have URLs demonstrating how LSMs are able to load on kernels newer than 2.6.35?

Comment: Thanks for your idea, @sebasth: I'll investigate SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is shipped with SELinux and default policy. Depending on your requirements you can configure existing policies or write additional policies.

RHEL provides some documentation on [SELinux Administration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/). More material is listed in [SELinux wiki](http://www.selinuxproject.org/).